# problema al generar css con node-sass

Tags: nodejs, npm, sass

para agregar la conversión de sass a css en mi node seguí los [pasos de este tutorial](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/watch-and-compile-sass-in-five-quick-steps--cms-28275), tras completarlo mi archivo `package.json` luce así:

```
{
  "name": "kimera",
  "version": "0.4.4",
  "description": "A Modern CSS and JS framework based on flexbox and custom tags",
  "main": "css/kimera.css",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "scss": "node-sass -watch scss -o css"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/JorgeAntrax/kimera.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "css",
    "scss",
    "flexbox",
    "responsive",
    "framework",
    "modular",
    "library",
    "etiquetas",
    "html5",
    "css3",
    "grid",
    "libreria css",
    "plantillas"
  ],
  "author": "Leonardo Quintana Juarez",
  "email": "spicer_94@hotmail.com",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/JorgeAntrax/kimera/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "http://kimera.comli.com",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "@types/npm": "^2.0.29",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "mocha": "^5.0.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.8.3"
  }
}
```

Si se necesita [aquí puedes hallar](https://pastebin.com/S1Wpcz08) mi `package-lock.json`.

El problema es que al tratar de correr `npm run scss` obtengo el siguiente error:

> path.js:28
>
> throw new TypeError('Path must be a string. Received ' + inspect(path));

Mis versiones de npm y de node son...

```
npm -version
```

5.5.1

```
node -v
```

v8.9.1

¿Qué debo de cambiar para que funcione?

Answer (score 2):

Instala nuevamente el node-sass con esta version

```
npm install node-sass@4.7.2
```

si te genera algun problema al momento de la instalacion prueba lo siguiente

```
npm rebuild node-sass@4.7.2 --force
```

si con esto te sigue dando problema el node-sass te guio a realizarlo manualmente.

ve al repositorio en github: https://github.com/sass/node-sass

procede a realizar la descarga o clonar el repositorio, luego descomprime y temdras el directorio node-sass ubicalo o reemplazalo en tu proyecto en el directorio node-modules

En tu archivo package-lock.json ubica y reemplaza por lo siguiente:

```
"node-sass": {
  "version": "4.7.2",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/node-sass/-/node-sass-4.7.2.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-CaV+wLqZ7//Jdom5aUFCpGNoECd7BbNhjuwdsX/LkXBrHl8eb1Wjw4HvWqcFvhr5KuNgAk8i/myf/MQ1YYeroA==",
  "dev": true,
  "requires": {
    "async-foreach": "0.1.3",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "cross-spawn": "3.0.1",
    "gaze": "1.1.2",
    "get-stdin": "4.0.1",
    "glob": "7.1.2",
    "in-publish": "2.0.0",
    "lodash.assign": "4.2.0",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "4.5.0",
    "lodash.mergewith": "4.6.1",
    "meow": "3.7.0",
    "mkdirp": "0.5.1",
    "nan": "2.8.0",
    "node-gyp": "3.6.2",
    "npmlog": "4.1.2",
    "request": "2.79.0",
    "sass-graph": "2.2.4",
    "stdout-stream": "1.4.0",
    "true-case-path": "1.0.2"
  }
```

ya con esto no te debe generar problema alguno, en tal caso que quieras reconstruir la libreria node-sass te invito a revisar el README.md de node-sass en la seccion ## Rebuilding binaries. lo muestro para interes de cualquier lector:

````
## Rebuilding binaries

Node-sass includes pre-compiled binaries for popular platforms, to add a binary for your platform follow these steps:

Check out the project:

```bash
git clone --recursive https://github.com/sass/node-sass.git
cd node-sass
npm install
node scripts/build -f  # use -d switch for debug release
# if succeeded, it will generate and move
# the binary in vendor directory.
```
````